What extensions are needed to support WebGL 2 with OpenGL 3,3?
I'm trying to run a web based game on a PC with Ubuntu installed. It says Your browser does not support graphics API "WebGL 2" which is required for this content. I've checked and WebGL 2 is enabled in the browser.
The PC is old, so I tried to find out whether the GPU supports webgl 2. I found that the GPU supports OpenGL 3.3.
This site says WebGL 2 requires ... OpenGL 3.3 with some extensions on Linux. What extensions do I need to get?
